# Is there a standard quantifier notation for an exact number of true values?

Tags: logic, notation, first-order-logic, quantifiers, satisfiability

When working with [SAT Solvers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_satisfiability_problem), I need to write quantifiers that give the total number of true values.  The usual quantitiers $\forall$ and $\exists$ do not suffice. Is there a standard notation for writing the following statements?

- Exactly one of $x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4$ is true.
- At least two of $x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4$ are true.
- No more than two of $x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4$ are true.

Comment: For the first you can use $\exists ! _i x_i \text{ is true} $. In other words $\exists !$ means that there exists a unique (something) such that (something).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Generalized quantifiers](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/generalized-quantifiers/#univ) :

> $(∃_{=n})$ or $(∃^{=n})$ for "exactly $n$".

And :

> $(∃^{\ge n})$ for "at least $n$".

You can see also : Heinz-Dieter Ebbinghaus & Jörg Flum, [Finite Model Theory](https://books.google.it/books?id=jIFpliJXCw8C&pg=PA58), Springer (2nd ed., 1999), **Ch.3.4 Logics with Counting Quantifiers**, page 58-on.

Comment: Is this a standard notation or something unique to the cited Stanford paper?   I just did a search on "Generalized quantifers" you provided and saw a *Q* notation in some of the hits: http://ebusiness.mit.edu/research/papers/110%20SMadnick%20Source%20Selection.p and http://www.math.helsinki.fi/logic/opetus/ext_elem_logic/beatcs.pdf The examples included $Q_{most}$, $Q_{>=3}$, and $Q_{half}$.

Comment: @RaymondHettinger - it not very "standard" because generalized q are not often used.